# How can I generate sitemaps on heroku?

Tags: amazon-s3, heroku, sitemap

I've seen some older threads on generating a sitemap on heroku...the challenges being it needs to be stored on S3 and configuring it so that the sitemap is legitimate since it is hosted elsewhere.

I didn't see anything definitive, however, some conversations and suggested patches.

Is there something out-of-the-box that can work well with heroku?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am awaiting for the s3 version of sitemap_generator and if it does what it says, that should be it.

Answer (score 10):

Based on the article of https://github.com/kjvarga/sitemap_generator

> You should add the URL of the sitemap index file to public/robots.txt to help search engines >find your sitemaps. The URL should be the complete URL to the sitemap index. For example:
>
> Sitemap: http://www.example.com/sitemap_index.xml.gz

If you're using google webmaster tools, which only allowing you to specify a url of your host, maybe you can create a controller & action to just redirect to the sitemap.xml on your S3. And then specify that url in webmaster tools.
http://www.billrowell.com/2012/02/01/create-an-xml-sitemap-on-heroku-via-amazon-s3/

If you are looking for uploading to S3, this should help:
https://github.com/kjvarga/sitemap_generator/wiki/Generate-Sitemaps-on-read-only-filesystems-like-Heroku

Comment: You can, as well, configure the redirection in your routes, so you don't need to add a controller: `get '/sitemap.xml.gz', to: redirect('https://your-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/sitemaps/sitemap.xml.gz')`

Comment: I can verify this method worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I've previously done this via route named sitemap.xml to a controller that builds a sitemap dynamically - rather than scraping the site and having a hard coded sitemap.xml that has to be stored somewhere. I guess it depends on your app and the frequency at which the URLs are changing.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak English not well.
But explan to you my code.
xml is create using 'xmlbuilder'.

```
CreateXmlFile(request, response, next, function(request, response, next, xml){
      response.type('text/xml');
      response.send(xml);
      if(typeof next == "function"){
        next();
      }
    });
```

Comment: Sorry you can using to transrate Korean to English?? Google transrate is good :).

Comment: xml 은 절대적인 파일이라는게 중요하지 않습니다. 그저 검색봇(search box)이 해당 주소를 방문하면 xml 문서를 보여주는게 중요합니다. 그래서 실제 파일이 필요하지 않습니다.